# RADIUS is ignoring request to authentication address

Tags: networking, authentication, radius

RADIUS only works if I use localhost. I can't use its IP address.

Output of: `radtest user password localhost 1812 testing123`:

```
Sending Access-Request of id 251 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=251, length=33
    Reply-Message = "Hello, user"
```

But if I want to use its IP address

Output of `radtest user password 192.168.2.218 1812 testing123`:

```
Sending Access-Request of id 28 to 192.168.2.218 port 1812
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 28 to 192.168.2.218 port 1812
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 28 to 192.168.2.218 port 1812
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 1812
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
radclient: no response from server for ID 28 socket 3
```

Output of `sudo freeradius -X`:

```
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 192.168.2.218 port 46554
Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 192.168.2.218 port 46554
Ready to process requests.
```

The user entry in `/etc/freeradius/users`:

```
"user"          Cleartext-Password := "password"
                Reply-Message = "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

The entry in `clients.conf`:

```
client 192.168.2.218 {
    ipaddr = 192.168.2.218
    secret = testing123
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem I had to comment out `client localhost {` and `ipaddr = 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/freeradius/clients.conf`.

Comment out the following

```
#client localhost {

        #  Allowed values are:
        #       dotted quad (1.2.3.4)
        #       hostname    (radius.example.com)
#       ipaddr = 127.0.0.1

        #  OR, you can use an IPv6 address, but not both
        #  at the same time.
#       ipv6addr = ::   # any.  ::1 == localhost
```

and then add

```
client openwrt {
        ipaddr = 192.168.2.1
        secret = testing123
        require_message_authenticator = yes
```

Allow port `1812` and `1813`

```
sudo ufw allow 1812

sudo ufw allow 1813
```

Now my router uses radius.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems above were all firewall related. On Ubuntu 16.04 with iptables disabled, I had no trouble. I just added the net, restarted the daemon, and it worked.

```
client 192.168.0.0/16 {
   secret          = your_pw_here
   shortname       = reserved192
}
```

The output of `sudo freeradius -X`
was rather long, but entertaining.

bottom line:  `Sending Access-Accept of id blah to ip-blah port blah`